# Wordpress plugin creation how to execute .sql in order to insert multiple rows at activation of plugin

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin which upon activation i create my database table.  I have an .sql file which has ~2000 rows of data and i would like to execute it after the creation of my database table. Which do you think is the best way to insert those data upon the plugin activation?

I know it is going to execute on activation hook - but is it possible to execute an .sql file or do i have to find another way and somehow execute each row through $wpdb->insert()?

If you need any further infomation please ask and i will provide - i also searched but couldn't find the same case.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the best way by which you can achieve this as first it will initialize `custom_create_plugin_tables` and next it will initialize `custom_insert_data_custom_table`

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'custom_create_plugin_tables' )
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'custom_insert_data_custom_table' );

function custom_create_plugin_tables()
{
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_name';

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
          id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          column_two varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          column_three int(11) NOT NULL,
          UNIQUE KEY id (id)
              );";

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }

function custom_insert_data_custom_table()
{
      global $wpdb;
      $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_name';

      $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'column_two' => "column_two_value", 'column_three' => 'column_three_value' ));
     require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
     dbDelta( $rows_affected );

}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks ok but i have an actual .SQL file. With that way i will have to type ~2000 `$wpdb->insert()` but that's not the case. I want to find a way and execute the whole .sql file without the need of adding ~2000 lines of code.